# Axios GET Request works in Postman but throws 400 error - Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working through a full stack project. So far, I have created a login and register which both work and they return a jwt web token. I am trying to make a GET request to (/api/profile/me) to get the logged in user profile but I get a 400 error. It works in Postman but fails in react.

[image]

actions - profile.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR } from './types';

// Get current users profile
export const getCurrentProfile = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/profile/me');

      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PROFILE_ERROR,
        payload: {
          msg: error.response.statusText,
          status: error.response.status,
        },
      });
    }
  };
};
```

reducers - profile.js

```
import { PROFILE_ERROR, GET_PROFILE } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  profile: null,
  profiles: [],
  repos: [],
  loading: true,
  error: {},
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case PROFILE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Dashboard where I want to load the action

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getCurrentProfile } from '../../actions/profile';
const Dashboard = () => {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const profile = useSelector((state) => state.profile);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCurrentProfile());
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <p className="dashboard-heading">Dashboard</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Are your frontend and backend apps running on the same port "5000"?

Comment: yes they are running on the same port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue by console logging the error response data. It returned the message

> "There is no profile for this user"

meaning that I used a different user than the one I used in Postman.